# Derivative of an integral wrt a different variable

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a small problem which I just have no idea on how to calculate, I am trying to find the derivative of $p$ of an integral that is with respect to $y$ (and ultimately solve the equation).

$$\frac{d}{dp}[2\int_0^1(p-y)^2{y^{x-1}(1-y)^{-x}}dy]=0$$

Answer (score 5):

Your tool is [differentiation under the integral.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral)  Essentially:
$$\frac{d}{dp}\int_a^bf(y,p)\,dy = \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial p}f(y,p)\,dy$$

So:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dp}[2\int_0^1(p-y)^2{y^{x-1}(1-y)^{-x}}dy]&=2\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial p}(p-y)^2{y^{x-1}(1-y)^{-x}}dy\\
&=2\int_0^1 2(p-y){y^{x-1}(1-y)^{-x}}dy\\
\end{align}$$

To go further, we'd need to know for what variable you are trying to solve, and what in the world the $x$'s are doing there. `:)`

Comment: Note that my equation for differentiation under the integral is different than Wikipedia's because they assume that the limits are functions of $p$.